# Ask questions about APIs available in Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge

I'm building a viewer environment using Autodesk Forge.

Currently, i'm developing using the 'Forge-Extension project' on github.
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions

The aim is to view files in .rvt format and .ifc format.
And i'm going to use API to express the property information of the imported file in a tree structure. Are these APIs provided by Forge?

And i am wondering if it also provides an API to write notes on properties.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the Forge Viewer allows you only to visualize the model and it's properties coming from the original CAD program.
To have custom notes/properties (or add new one or modify existing one), you must keep in mind that if there is need to embed them back into the original file, then an extra step will be needed.
Thus, there could be two approaches here:

1. Keep the custom notes and properties outside the model, in an external database. Then have an extension which, upon model loading, will get those custom notes/properties and show them in the viewer along with embed properties.
2. Have an extension to record the custom notes/properties and then upon sort of save, to trigger the [Forge Design Automation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/) service, to write the new data into the source file (for now mainly Revit, Autocad, Inventor and 3ds Max). For more info check this tutorial: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels

This is just a brief overview, but if you need more insights, try to reach for a one-on-one a Forge expert using this platform: https://calendly.com/autodeskforge
(more information here: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/the-doctor-is-in)